# Regex word count - matching words with apostrophe

Tags: regex

I'm trying to count words using Regex, with the following pattern:
    `@"\\w+"`

This works, however it's matching it's as:

- it
- s

Is there a better way to match words that contain punctuation?

Also, words surrounded by punctuation, for example `'word'` should also be matched (withhout the ')

Comment: What language is this? Obj-C?

Comment: Regex implementation differs 4rm language2language..where's the language tag!

Comment: Are you assuming the string contains only valid words?  Why not just split the string using `' '` as the delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one way to test for such cases is:

```
@"\\w+(?:'\\w+)?"
```

So it will match both `its` and `it's`, but only `its` in `its'`.

Answer (score 1):

I find this style readable, this is with hyphenated words.

`'?([a-zA-z'-]+)'?`

this is without hyphenation

`'?([a-zA-z']+)'?`

if you want quick and dirty regex testing with visual feedback you can use one of the many online regex testing tools, i like [rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/) (even for non ruby regex testing)