# Count number of words across an array of strings

Tags: mongodb

I have the following aggregation:

```
db.subtitles.aggregate()
    .match({})
    .group({_id: {chunkId: "$chunk_id"}, text: { $push:"$text"}})
```

What this will render is a result so:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "chunkId" : "ffdd704b-c441-4b49-a32e-fc2277d99250"
    },
    "text" : [
        "Mula doon, sumasama ako sa grocery, sa palengke, sinusundan ko saan napupunta ang pera.",
        "Nagkakaroon sila ng resibo na makikita sa kanilang device.",
        "Parang ganun na nga, pero…",
        "Kaya parang akong naging buhay na QuickBooks. Gusto ko malaman kung ano ang ginagawa ng mga tao sa pera, magkano kinita nila. ",
        "Sa kanilang email o text ay may impormasyon na masasabi mo na \"Itong numero na ito, itong text ay galing halimbawa sa Bank of America, at kumpirmado ito\"",
        "Mga 4,500 na interbyu o mahigit pa. Sa buong Silangang Africa, sub Saharan Africa at sa Timog Asia.",
        "Sa mga umuusbong na merkado, kapag nagbabayad sila ng kuryente, o kapag sumweldo sila.",
        "Hindi ko na gustong makita ang nangyari 3 taon nakalipas. Nais ko lang malaman kung kaya mo itong bayaran sa katapusan ng buwan.",
        "Saan ako magpunta?"
    ]
},
…
```

What I'd like to do is add another field to this group that gives me a total word count for the `text` array.  In this case roughly 136 words.

How could I adjust my aggregation to accomplish this?

Comment: I have updated my answer please check and let me know if you need different output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate words before grouping, so you don't need to deal with array of strings but with a single "text" field.

Starting from v4.2 you can benefit from [$regexFindAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFindAll/#exp._S_regexFindAll) operator:

```
db.subtitles.aggregate([ 
    { $match: {} },
    { $addFields: { words: { $size: { $regexFindAll: { input: "$text", regex: /\w+/ }}}}}, 
    { $group: {_id: {chunkId: "$chunk_id"}, text: { $push:"$text"}, words: {$sum: "$words"}}}
])
```

Please read the docs regarding collation to ensure proper behaviour of `\w+` regexp. You may want to add some other characters there, e.g. apostrophe etc depending on language. Precise counting may require quite sophisticated regexs especially for non-english strings. See [Regex word count - matching words with apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677008/regex-word-count-matching-words-with-apostrophe) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [$stLenCP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/) and [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage

```
db.subtitle.aggregate([
    { $match: { "_id": ObjectId("5d5b889c33acba0b89b97cda") } },
    { $addFields: {
        "length": {
           $strLenCP: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$text",
                initialValue: "",
                in: { $concat: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
              }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Comment: This actually won't work (i.e. `$strLenCP` doesn't work on arrays) and it's not the string length rather I need to know but rather the combined number of words across all of those elements, as the question states